# How do I cache steps in GitHub actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

Say I have a GitHub actions workflow with 2 steps.

1. Download and compile my application's dependencies.
2. Compile and test my application

My dependencies rarely change and the compiled dependencies can be safely cached until I next change the lock-file that specifies their versions.

Is a way to save the result of the first step so that in future workflow can skip over that step?

Comment: While bitoiu's answer is correct that there's no explicit caching feature in GitHub Actions today, you do get implicit caching across steps in a workflow within a given workflow run. This happens because GitHub volume mounts your repo into Docker for each step. Any changes you make in one step persist on disk into the next steps for that workflow run. Of course, this will not cache a dependency build across runs as you've asked, but others may find the ability to have _some_ caching useful. I don't think this feature is documented.

Comment: Another thing you could do is push your build dependency cache (e.g., as a tar) out to S3 / Minio / etc like how [GitLab's distributed caching system](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html#distributed-runners-caching) works.  You'd have to do the requests to/from S3 or similar manually for now until the GitHub Actions product adds a feature like this.  How much time (if any) this saves you certainly depends on the size of your dependencies and how fast GitHub Actions pulls from S3.  I haven't tested this yet myself.

Comment: "GitHub will remove any cache entries that have not been accessed in over 7 days." quoted from GitHub's documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#usage-limits-and-eviction-policy

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Most use-cases are covered by existing actions, for example:

- [`actions/setup-node`](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) for JS
- [`docker/build-push-action`](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) for Docker

---

Custom caching is supported via the [cache action](https://github.com/actions/cache). It works across both jobs and workflows within a repository. See also: [GitHub docs](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows) and [Examples](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/master/examples.md).

Consider the [following example](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/9ab95382c899bf0953a0c6c1374373fc40456ffe/examples.md#node---npm):

```yaml
name: GitHub Actions Workflow with NPM cache

on: push

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Cache NPM dependencies
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: ~/.npm
        key: ${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache-

    - name: Install NPM dependencies
      run: npm install
```

How caching works step-by-step:

- At the `Cache NPM dependencies` step, the action will check if there's an existing cache for the current `key`
- If no cache is found, it will check spatial matches using `restore-keys`. In this case, if `package-lock.json` changes, it will fall back to a previous cache. It is useful to prefix keys and restore keys with the OS and name of the cache, as it shouldn't load files for a different type of cache or OS.
- If any cache is found, it will load the files to `path`
- The CI continues to the next step and can use the filed loaded from the cache. In this case, `npm install` will use the files in `~/.npm` to save downloading them over the network (note that for NPM, caching `node_modules` directly is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61953857/2771889)).
- At the end of the CI run a post-action is executed to save the updated cache in case the `key` changes. This is not explicitly defined in the workflow, rather it is built into the cache action to take care of both loading and saving the cache.

---

You can also build your own reusable caching logic with [@actions/cache](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/master/packages/cache) such as:

- [1-liner NPM cache](https://github.com/c-hive/gha-npm-cache)
- [1-liner Yarn cache](https://github.com/c-hive/gha-yarn-cache)

---

<sub>*Old answer:*</sub>

<sub>Native caching is not currently possible, [expected to be implemented by mid-November 2019](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Caching-files-between-GitHub-Action-executions/m-p/30974/highlight/true#M630).</sub>

<sub>You can use artifacts ([1](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact), [2](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact)) to move directories between jobs (within 1 workflow) as proposed on the [GH Community board](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Caching-files-between-GitHub-Action-executions/m-p/30172/highlight/true#M130). This, however, [doesn't work across workflows](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact/issues/3).</sub>

Comment: Won't this example still run the `npm install` step on every push unless you include something like `if: steps.cache-deps.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'` and `id: cache-deps` for the cache step?

Comment: Yes, it will, but it will load the dependencies from the cache.

Comment: @thisismydesign and what will be the benefits of loading the dependencies from the cache if I still have to wait for the `npm install` step?

Comment: Just an FYI for those unaware, this sends and receives the cache with GitHub remotely. So if you're using locally managed GitHub runners (which is awesome btw) then you incur the time and cost of uploading and downloading these caches.

Comment: @DannyFeliz You can choose to cache `node_modules` but it's not recommended: https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/9ab95382c899bf0953a0c6c1374373fc40456ffe/examples.md#node---npm Caching `~/.npm` will save you at least the downloading of packages (could be other things on top as well, I'm not sure).

Comment: how would you use cache but at the same time matrix? in order to test with different node versions?

Comment: This answer doesn't actually explain how to consume the cache in a subsequent job, which is the entire point of `@action/cache`. It just repeats GitHub's pointless documentation which also doesn't explain how to consume the cache.

Comment: @Distortum The cache is consumed as explained in the answer and in the docs. It is saved after each run. I'm afraid the misunderstanding is on your side.

Comment: For other languages, the official `cache` repo has plenty of examples of how to cache your dependencies. See: https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md

Comment: Something that was not at all clear to me and is not explicitly mentioned *anywhere* in the documentation, is that when a cache search misses, the cache action evaluates the paths to subsequently store **at the end of the job**. I was confused why every example didn't have two uses of the cache action (1 to try to restore and then 1 to store after generating the files only if the cache missed), since the docs make it sound like the cache stores when the action is used, not at the end. It's somewhat implied by the cache only storing files if the job was successful but it could be more explicit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60491837/saving-cache-on-job-failure-in-github-actions/75961093#75961093

Answer (score 15):

The `cache` action can only cache the contents of a folder. So if there is such a folder, you may win some time by caching it.

For instance, if you use some imaginary `package-installer` (like Python's `pip` or `virtualenv`, or NodeJS' `npm`, or anything else that puts its files into a folder), you can win some time by doing it like this:

```
    - uses: actions/cache@v2
      id: cache-packages  # give it a name for checking the cache hit-or-not
      with:
        path: ./packages/  # what we cache: the folder
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-packages-${{ hashFiles('**/packages*.txt') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-packages-
    - run: package-installer packages.txt
      if: steps.cache-packages.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
```

So what's important here:

1. We give this step a name, `cache-packages`
2. Later, we use this name for conditional execution: `if`, `steps.cache-packages.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'`
3. Give the cache action a path to the folder you want to cache: `./packages/`
4. Cache key: something that depends on the hash of your input files. That is, if any `packages.txt` file changes, the cache will be rebuilt.
5. The second step, package installer, will only be run if there was no cache

For users of `virtualenv`: if you need to activate some shell environment, you have to do it in every step. Like this:

```
- run: . ./environment/activate && command
```

Answer (score 4):

> My dependencies rarely change and the compiled dependencies can be safely cached until I next change the lock-file that specifies their versions. Is a way to save the result of the first step so that in future workflow can skip over that step?

The first step being:

> Download and compile my application's dependencies.

**GitHub Actions themselves will not do this for you.** The only advice I can give you is that you adhere to Docker best practices in order to ensure that if Actions do make use of docker caching, your image could be re-used instead of rebuilt. See: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache

> When building an image, Docker steps through the instructions in your Dockerfile, executing each in the order specified. As each instruction is examined, Docker looks for an existing image in its cache that it can reuse, rather than creating a new (duplicate) image.

This also implies that the underlying system of GitHub Actions can/will leverage the Docker caching.

However things like compilation, Docker won't be able to use the cache mechanism, so I suggest you think very well if this is something you desperately need. The alternative is to download the compiled/processed files from an artifact store (Nexus, NPM, MavenCentral) to skip that step. You do have to weight the benefits vs the complexity you are adding to your build on this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll go back to using Circle and Travis until GitHub gets this feature. :)

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation where Travis does this?

Comment: Here's an [example](https://github.com/2color/auroqueue/blob/master/Dockerfile) of a Dockerfile which leverages docker caching for the dependencies.

It's worth mentioning that the cache will only be leveraged assuming that every time the image is build, it runs on the same machine (and therefor same docker cache). 
I'm not sure if all actions share the same "docker context", but I assume that'd be a major factor.

Comment: I just tried this by running a Docker based action I had created 5 times. Each time, the docker was regenerated from scratch. So, doesn't look like it uses the same docker context (as of now atleast). I don't have a way of checking if the same runner was used or not, so maybe that was the case too. Overall - doesnt seem a very reliable method as of today

Comment: @AbdealiJK you might find useful my answer if you are using a Docker based action: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58752958/4095830

Answer (score 4):

This is **now** natively supported using: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows.

This is achieved by using the new **cache action**: https://github.com/actions/cache

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Docker in your WorkFlows, as [@peterevans answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640110/4095830), GitHub now supports caching through the [cache](https://github.com/actions/cache) action, but it has its limitations.

For that reason, you might find useful [this action](https://github.com/whoan/docker-build-with-cache-action) to bypass GitHub's action limitations.

> **Disclaimer:** I created the action to support cache before GitHub did it officially, and I still use it because of its simplicity and flexibility.

Comment: Are there any other solutions that allow to cache layers without authenticating?

Answer (score 1):

I'll summarize the two options:

1. Caching
2. Docker

### Caching

You can add a command in your workflow to cache directories. When that step is reached, it'll check if the directory that you specified was previously saved. If so, it'll grab it. If not, it won't. Then in further steps you write checks to see if the cached data is present. For example, say you are compiling some dependency that is large and doesn't change much. You could add a cache step at the beginning of your workflow, then a step to build the contents of the directory if they aren't there. The first time that you run it won't find the files but subsequently it will and your workflow will run faster.

Behind the scenes, GitHub is uploading a zip of your directory to github's own AWS storage. They purge anything older than a week or if you hit a 2GB limit.

### Docker

Docker is a little more complex and it means that you have to have a dockerhub account and manage two things now. But it's way more powerful. Instead of saving just a directory, you'll save an entire computer! What you'll do is make a Dockerfile that will have in it all your dependencies, like apt-get and python pip lines or even long compilation. Then you'll build that docker image and publish it on dockerhub. Finally, you'll have your tests set to run on that new docker image, instead of on eg, ubuntu-latest. And from now on, instead of installing dependencies, it'll just download the image.

You can automate this further by storing that Dockerfile in the same GitHub repo as the project and then write a job with steps that will download the latest docker image, rebuild if necessary just the changed steps, and then upload to dockerhub. And then a job which "needs" that one and uses the image. That way your workflow will both update the docker image if needed and also use it.

The downsides is that your deps will be in one file, the Dockerfile, and the tests in the workflow, so it's not all together. Also, if the time to download the image is more than the time to build the dependencies, this is a poor choice.

---

I think that each one has upsides and downsides. Caching is only good for really simple stuff, like compiling into .local. If you need something more extensive, Docker is the most powerful.