# Saving cache on job failure in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I am using the GitHub [cache](https://github.com/actions/cache) action, but I noticed that the no cache will be created if the job fails. From the [docs](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#using-the-cache-action):

> If the job completes **successfully**, the action creates a new cache with the contents of the path directory.

A stripped down version of my workflow YAML file:

```
name: Build

on: [push]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@master
        with:
          node-version: '10.x'

      - name: Get yarn cache path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"

      - name: Restore yarn cache
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        id: yarn-cache
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

      - name: Install yarn dependencies
        run: yarn install

      - name: Build
        run: yarn build
```

I noticed that if my `Build` step fails the `cache` post-step will be skipped unnecessarily, which causes the installed dependencies to not be cached. This requires subsequent runs to download dependencies again, slowing down the job.

Is there a way to always cache the dependencies, even when the build step fails?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can now use the `actions/cache/save` action to save the cache right after it is populated, and before any tests (or anything that might fail the job) runs. This is how issue [actions/cache#92](https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/92) was resolved in the end.

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  .
  . // restore if need be
  .
  - name: Build
    run: /build.sh
  - uses: actions/cache/save@v3
    if: always() // or any other condition to invoke the save action
    with:
      path: path/to/dependencies
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/lockfiles') }}
```

https://github.com/actions/cache/tree/main/save#always-save-cache

Answer (score 22):

In the official version of the action, no it's not possible to cache dependencies if the build fails.  See [this line](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/826785142ab6c0b7ce4ad2eadf642c6351ca6483/action.yml#L21) in the cache action's manifest:

```yaml
runs:
  using: 'node12'
  main: 'dist/restore/index.js'
  post: 'dist/save/index.js'
  post-if: 'success()'
```

It will only run the post-step if the job succeeds.  I don't know the original reasoning for this, but there are a few issues opened around this idea.  In [this issue](https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/92) a user [forked the action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/always-upload-cache) to change the `post-if` to `always()`, which may be what you're after, assuming you're willing to run an unofficial action.

Comment: Is there a reason why it's not configurable in the official action ?

Comment: Now it is: https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/a2ed59d39b352305bdd2f628719a53b2cc4f9613/action.yml#L40 but seems broken https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/1315