# How to cache yarn packages in GitHub Actions

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, github-actions

I am using GitHub Actions to build my TypeScript project.
Everytime I run action I am waiting 3 minutes for all dependencies to get installed.

Is there way to cache yarn dependencies, so build time will be faster?

I tried this:

```yaml
     - name: Get yarn cache directory path
       id: yarn-cache-dir-path
       run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"

     - uses: actions/cache@v1
       id: yarn-cache # use this to check for `cache-hit` (`steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'`)
       with:
         path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
         key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
         restore-keys: |
           ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

    - name: Install yarn
      run: npm install -g yarn

    - name: Install project dependencies
      run: yarn
```

but build time is still same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment next to the `id` field for the caching step:

> Use this to check for `cache-hit` (`steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'`)

You're missing a conditional `if` property that determines whether the step should be run:

```yaml
- name: Install yarn
  run: npm install -g yarn

- name: Install project dependencies
  if: steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' # Over here!
  run: yarn
```

P.S. You should probably use the [Setup NodeJS](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) GitHub Action that additionally sets up Yarn for you:

```yaml
- uses: actions/setup-node@v1
  with:
    node-version: '10.x' # The version spec of the version to use.
```

See the [`action.yml` file](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/blob/master/action.yml) for a full list of valid inputs.

---

EDIT: As it turns out, Yarn is included in the list of [software installed on the GitHub-hosted Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (`ubuntu-latest`/`ubuntu-18.04`) runner](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md), so there's no need to include a step to globally install Yarn.

Comment: This is my config: https://pastebin.com/CCgFjEW0 I am already using `actions/setup-node@v1`, so I dont need to install yarn?

Comment: Sadly, the conditional "if" not helped.

Comment: For the first comment, see the edit I've made to my answer. As for the second comment, could you indicate _how_ the conditional `if` property does not help?

Comment: Thanks, that works. But action fails on running jest. `jest --config=jest.config.js
/bin/sh: 1: jest: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127` Also, action succeeds on disabling cache.

Answer (score 106):

1. Using `actions/setup-node@v2` or newer:

   ```yaml
   - name: Set up Node.js
     uses: actions/setup-node@v3
     with:
       node-version: '16'
       cache: 'yarn'

   - name: Install project dependencies
     run: yarn
   ```

   `actions/setup-node@v2` or newer has caching built in so you no longer need to set up `actions/cache`.
2. Using `actions/setup-node@v1` & caching Yarn global cache with `actions/cache`:

   ```yaml
   - name: Set up Node.js
     uses: actions/setup-node@v1
     with:
       node-version: '16'

   - name: Get yarn cache directory path
     id: yarn-cache-dir-path
     run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"

   - uses: actions/cache@v3
     id: yarn-cache # use this to check for `cache-hit` (`steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'`)
     with:
       path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
       key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
       restore-keys: |
       ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

   - name: Install project dependencies
     run: yarn --prefer-offline
   ```

The caching code above only caches and restores the Yarn [global cache directory](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/cache), it doesn't cache the `node_modules` directory itself.

To improve the installation speed, you need to tell Yarn to use cached downloads (in the cache directory mentioned above) during installation whenever possible instead of downloading from the server:

```
- name: Install project dependencies
  run: yarn --prefer-offline
```

3. Caching `node_modules` with `actions/cache` (**not** recommended)

   You can also cache the `node_modules` directory directly and skip the running `yarn` when the cache is available.

   But it is not recommended because:

   - `yarn` is good at utilizing global cache. If the dependencies are already available in global cache, `yarn` can finish running in less than 1 second. (see [comment from @mvlabat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010294/how-to-cache-yarn-packages-in-github-actions/62244232#comment114239256_62244232)).
   - `node_modules` could be corrupted. It is safer to re-run `yarn` every time and let `yarn` decides whether to get the files from cache or not (as `yarn` will try to validate the cache before using it).

   ```yaml
   - name: Set up Node.js
     uses: actions/setup-node@v1
     with:
       node-version: '16'

   - name: Get yarn cache directory path
       id: yarn-cache-dir-path
       run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"

   - name: Cache yarn cache
       uses: actions/cache@v3
       id: cache-yarn-cache
       with:
       path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
       key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
       restore-keys: |
           ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

   - name: Cache node_modules
       id: cache-node-modules
       uses: actions/cache@v3
       with:
       path: node_modules
       key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ matrix.node-version }}-nodemodules-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
       restore-keys: |
           ${{ runner.os }}-${{ matrix.node-version }}-nodemodules-

   - run: yarn
       if: |
       steps.cache-yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' ||
       steps.cache-node-modules.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to skip the yarn step if you have a cache hit only by `${{ runner.os }}-${{ matrix.node-version }}-nodemodules-`. Since it doesn't require the same `yarn.lock` hash, does it mean that I may get outdated dependencies and skip the `yarn` step, which could have updated them?

Comment: Also, `yarn` itself is pretty much able to detect whether dependencies have to be updated or not. For instance, when running `yarn` install locally the second time, it finishes in less than 1 second. I think the `yarn` step shouldn't be skipped in any scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, guys! I totally agree. I've updated the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Can anyone else clarify that the 'non recommended' one is fit for use now that we also check for the cached yarn.lock in that last code example? i've tested adding/removing packages and seems to catch those differences reliably for me. thanks

Comment: Why cache node_modules is NOT recommended??

Comment: @Penguin @racemic You can cache node_modules and it would work just fine. But `node_modules` could be corrupted. It's safer to re-run `yarn` every time and let `yarn` decides whether to get the files from cache or not (assuming `yarn` will try to validate the cache before using it).

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. So your recommendation is the combination of caching `yarn.lock` and use `--prefer-offline` flag?

Comment: @PHD Yes, that's what I'm using in production.

Comment: We are using the "not recommended" approach with some success. Just an FYI for those unaware, this sends and receives the cache to and from GitHub remotely. So if you're using locally managed GitHub runners (which is awesome btw) then you incur the time and cost of uploading and downloading these caches.

Comment: Why are you not using `actions/cache@v2`? (The first block of code in your answer). Also which approach is desired? Your answer is a little messy/hard to understand.

Comment: @basickarl Thanks for the feedback! I've updated the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: `Run yarn --prefer-offline
  yarn --prefer-offline
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
➤ YN0050: The --prefer-offline flag is deprecated; use the --cached flag with 'yarn add' instead`

Comment: Option 2 is currently relevant again if using volta-cli/action

Comment: For me yarn is cached according to the node/setup action logs, but still the `yarn install` takes the same time as when doing a full install (this is with --prefer-offline, --offline fails). Common pattern across projects. Any ideas @QuangLam?

Comment: totally fine to cache node modules

Answer (score 42):

As the [readme](https://github.com/actions/setup-node#caching-global-packages-data) of the [github package](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) says:

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- uses: actions/setup-node@v2
  with:
    node-version: '14'
    cache: 'npm' # or yarn
- run: npm install
- run: npm test
```

## Edit:

Turns out that the way the docs were written was very misleading and they updated to make it clear that it **doesn't cache the `node_modules` folder, but only the global cache directory**, as stated in [this issue](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/416).

Also as stated by Mrchief in the comments:

> ... you'll still incur the `npm i time`, just save on download time from internet (if the module is in npm cache)

So you should still use this save time from downloading packages from internet, but if you want to cache `node_modules` folder, check the other answers where it uses [actions/cache](https://github.com/actions/cache).

You should also check [Quang Lam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62244232/9119186) answer and it's comments on why you **shouldn't** cache `node_modules` folder.

Comment: The other answers either don't use setup-node or use v1.

The caching was added in v2.

This should be the accepted answer now.

Comment: This method doesn't cache `node_modules`, rather the global cache (`.npm` in case of npm). So you'll still incur the `npm i` time, just save on download time from internet (if the module is in npm cache).

Comment: As @Mrchief stated, this does not actually cache your packages in the node_modules. They way they described it was quite misleading, but they did update their readme after some complaints. More info here: https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/416

Comment: @Vasco I updated my answer so it's clear what is actually being cached, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 12):

[`actions/setup-node`](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) supports caching [since v2](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/releases/tag/v2.2.0) with several custom [options](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/blob/094c36e88e2a3ffdf4d3a5bb935088ac39a46acc/docs/advanced-usage.md#caching-packages-data).

```yaml
- uses: actions/checkout@v3

- name: Setup Node.js
  uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: '16'
    cache: 'yarn'

- name: Install JS dependencies
  run: yarn install
```

Caching is done [as recommended](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/515d10b4fd9bb4858066bd5769f55bd498dcdd27/examples.md#node---yarn), only caching `yarn cache dir` and not `node_modules`. Caching `node_modules` is not recommended because it can lead to issues e.g. when node version changes.

---

<sub>*Old answer:*</sub>

<sub>This is a 1-liner cache specifically for Yarn: https://github.com/c-hive/gha-yarn-cache</sub>

<sub>It does caching as recommended by GitHub. Supports Yarn v1 and v2.</sub>

<sub>Same for NPM: https://github.com/c-hive/gha-npm-cache</sub>

Comment: For the people downvoting, please add some comments why you downvote this :) My guess is that this is build in now: https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#node---yarn

Comment: This is still a 1-liner vs 10 lines in the example.

Comment: Yeah, I also don't think this should be downvoted. Question is "How to cache yarn packages in GitHub Actions" and it answers it. I believe that other answers provide more depth, but this is really helpful for someone looking for a quick solution. Out of curiosity, did you test how performant this one liner is? Is it faster, slower, or the same as the longer ones?

Comment: It performs the same commands behind the scenes.