# Cache node_modules in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, yarnpkg, github-actions

I have a Yarn monorepo (workspace) with 2 packages: backend (Node.js/TypeScript) and frontend (React/Typescript).

`/package.json` (trimmed)

```
{
  "workspaces": [
    "backend",
    "frontend"
  ],
}
```

and I'm trying to add continuous integration with GitHub Actions and trying to use `actions/cache@v2` to cache the Yarn cache dir and all of the projects' `node_modules` dirs

`.github/workflows/CI.yml` (trimmed)

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get yarn cache directory path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"
          echo "::set-output name=version::$(yarn -v)"

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: |
            ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
            '**/node_modules'
            '**/.eslintcache'
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.version }}-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}

      - name: Install packages
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

I receive that the cache is stored and re-used for the consecutive runs:

```
key: Linux-yarn-1.22.10-143fef95c7228810cf502305eff3be1cbc468dc8a3e0b153a4311c0250aaef6f
Received 158645465 of 175422681 (90.4%), 151.3 MBs/sec
Received 175422681 of 175422681 (100.0%), 138.1 MBs/sec
Cache Size: ~167 MB (175422681 B)
/usr/bin/tar --use-compress-program zstd -d -xf /home/runner/work/_temp/08363700-9a23-447e-a80e-6f3dbec6068f/cache.tzst -P -C /home/runner/work/path
Cache restored successfully
Cache restored from key: Linux-yarn-1.22.10-143fef95c7228810cf502305eff3be1cbc468dc8a3e0b153a4311c0250aaef6f
```

but `yarn` still tries to resolve the dependencies:

```
yarn install --frozen-lockfile
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
yarn install v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
.....
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 40.07s.
```

My expectations are that it should be working as on my local machine:

```
$ yarn --frozen-lockfile
yarn install v1.22.10
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.72s.
```

Can I somehow improve my configuration to meet the expected result, or this GitHub Actions behaviour expected?

---

**Update:** When tried with the following paths:

```
          path: |
            '**/node_modules'
            '**/.eslintcache'
```

or:

```
          path: |
            'node_modules'
            '*/node_modules'
            '**/.eslintcache'
```

the cache size is 22 B. Probably not matching any of the `node_modules` dirs

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the improvements, but for the file names I've formatted them according to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327695/162350)

Comment: That's not guidance, just a random post on the formatting sandbox. If we were supposed to be following those everything might look like https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329360/248731!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, **removing the quotes** from the `path`s seems to have fixed the problem. And the size of the cache have increased almost twice

```
  - uses: actions/cache@v2
    id: yarn-cache
    with:
      path: |
        **/node_modules
        **/.eslintcache
        ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}

      key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-
```

`Run actions/cache@v2`

```
Received 213909504 of 305669200 (70.0%), 203.6 MBs/sec
Received 305669200 of 305669200 (100.0%), 185.6 MBs/sec
Cache Size: ~292 MB (305669200 B)
/usr/bin/tar --use-compress-program zstd -d -xf /home/runner/work/_temp/2e2d2a1d-04d7-44c3-829e-ec4e8faf394b/cache.tzst -P -C /home/runner/work/path
Cache restored successfully
Cache restored from key: Linux-yarn-143fef95c7228810cf502305eff3be1cbc468dc8a3e0b153a4311c0250aaef6f
```

`Run yarn install --frozen-lockfile`

```
yarn install v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.96s.
```

- [permalink to workflow](https://github.com/Teneff/withRetry/blob/2c770032f22892c077883e39ef95c013facdfff6/.github/workflows/build.yml)
- [master version](https://github.com/Teneff/withRetry/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml)

Comment: You're not supposed to cache `node_modules`, and instead use yarn cache directory.

Comment: @Emre my goal was to run the builds quickly. If you could describe the downsides of caching node_modules in an answer and compare the build speeds I'll accept it

Comment: You're right, there doesn't seem to be a better way.

Comment: There are 3 people in this thread saying that caching node_modules is not recommended without explaining why. At this point they make me doubt. Can someone explain if there is a problem or risk?

Comment: Some explanations why caching `node_modules` should be avoided. [Solution 3: Caching node_modules with actions/cache (NOT recommended)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62244232/13957900), [GitHub Cache Action](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#node---npm)

Comment: There's no strong reason to not cache `node_modules`, it's definitely possible and it will definitely be faster than caching the package manager's cache.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else looking for yarn caching implementation in gha, the following code is working best for me:

```
      - name: Get yarn cache directory path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)" 

      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: yarn-cache
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn --prefer-offline
        if: steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
```

It is best practice to NOT cache the `node_modules`.

Caching `node_modules` to determine which packages to install could led to improper cache busting.

Comment: Why is it a best practice not to cache `node_modules`?

Comment: the answer to your question is clearly included in the post @PaulRazvanBerg.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last sentence!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who needs to just cache `node_modules` here is the simplest example for eslint check. Remove latest `eslint` step if you don't need it.

```yaml
name: Lint check
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - dev
jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup node
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: '16'

    - name: Cache node modules
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: node_modules
        key: node_modules-${{hashFiles('yarn.lock')}}
        restore-keys: node_modules- # Take any latest cache if failed to find it for current yarn.lock

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: yarn

    - name: Run eslint on changed files
      uses: tj-actions/eslint-changed-files@v18
```

Keep in mind that `actions/cache@v3` keep cache for each branch separately, and only main branch can share its cache between others. So for each new branch the first run won't hit cache. To get that fixed I can provide a bit more complex workflow with reusing cache from main branch.

Comment: How are you updating the cached node_modules in case something changes in your app -> dependencies?

Comment: @NickM after restoring cache I run `yarn` which updates node_modules and later post step of cache@v3 caches it. But I'll update my answer to make it a bit more clever.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Based on your suggestion I was able to pull this off with app assets, will try with node_modules next.