# Verifying that npm install installed from cache

Tags: node.js, npm, github-actions, npm-install, npm-cache

How can I verify that npm install installed modules from the npm cache, from inside a Github action step?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64819132/1086398 could be useful to you. By deleting the cache and going again, and measuring the delta on how long it takes, that might allow you to infer this info?

Comment: That’s basically how I’m doing it now, but it’s not a good method because you are dependant in your network connection being constant.

Comment: It's a flawed method for sure, however the connection from the agents is going to be pretty consistent. You'd definitely be able to know doing this, as the speed difference would be obvious (something like 0.5s versus say, 3 secs). But for sure, its weak, and github are to blame for the lack of easy detection. It's worth noting you need to record the time serverside to rule out your own local connection. Have a step before that prints a timestamp and a step after that prints one.

Comment: Thanks - that’s what I have been doing! The install takes around 3 minutes with and without cache. People on SO keep asking me how I test, and what I was doing wasn’t good enough apparently. Do you know if private modules installed from Github private repo also get cached?

Comment: When you say private modules, what do you mean? Are you using a custom NPM registry to retrieve those, or do you mean you have `http://` or `git://` URLs in your package.json?

Comment: Another thing thats very important -- is the latest version of `package-lock.json` committed? As in, if you locally run `npm install`, and then `git status`, there are no pending changes in `package-lock.json`  right? And each time you run `npm install`, `package-lock.json` is not edited each time and stays constant/untouched?

Comment: And finally, is the version of NPM you are using locally the same as the one github is using? If it isn't, it could mean github considers the committed `package-lock.json` unstable if it runs a newer/older version and so mutates that file, breaking the cache.

Comment: (make sure you are using `npm ci` and not `npm install` on the github actions to enforce this)

Comment: Private modules - git+ssh:// in URLs in package.json, and using ssh aliases for private keys —> I.e. git+ssh://git@<ssh_alias>:<github_username>/<repo_name>

Comment: package-lock.json - I have latest checked in the repo, and yes I was using npm ci

Comment: After several days of trying to get this to work, I’ve tried pretty much every combination, setup-node with cache feature, setup-note using separate save cache / restore cache steps, but nothing works. All I can think is that it might be the private modules not getting cached, so they slow the install down. That’s why I want a verifiable way to test if a module got installed from cache or not.

Comment: Btw package-lock.json is created using same npm version that is on Github.

Comment: Right yes. I think the git+ssh thing not caching is a very possible reason. With package locking, the point is the exact version is recorded. NPM can use that and compare against whats in its cache to decide not to download something. But all that is predicated on the idea the target (usually an npm package with a strict version number) is immutable. A git+ssh source is not immutable, so it has no choice but to reach out every time. Otherwise, changes in the remote location would not be reflected. Its *possible* this might not happen if you add the commit hash to the URI...worth a try

Comment: The "real" fix to the issue of private modules, which i usually see in enterprise, is hosting your own private NPM registry somewhere and publishing to it. Much commercial software exists for that, but there's open source solutions as well if I remember correctly.

Comment: However, if you dont really care fo the case when the remote changed, you could try the `--prefer-offline` flag to `npm install` (and probably `ci`). That ought to make it not bother checking if there's a new version if it has whatever it got last time on hand. Coupled with using a commit hash in the git+ssh reference, you could then get updated by updating that hash which would break the cache. BTW a totally different angle to think about is if any dep (including transitive ones) has a postinstall step. Those would still run even if cached. Some packages (cypress is one) download binaries.

Comment: @adsy Awesome tips. I’m going to try a few things out over next few days

Comment: Hosting a private npm repository isn’t feasible for me right now.

Comment: I noticed that changes in private modules are not getting into consuming project, so cache appears to be working, at least in some cases (there are several private modules). However install times are still very long, so maybe, like you said, there’s a post install happening that is slowing everything. How do I detect and locate that?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I would definitely try adding a commit hash in the package.jsons for these deps to totally rule it out that it reaches out, as well as `--prefer-offline`. For the scripts -- you could try `npm install --ignore-scripts`. If the postinstalls were important, this could cause problems building but, it would let you verify if it's the cause of this problem at least.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be an npm cache by default. The boxes it spins up will be new every time. You can configure one using [actions/cache](https://github.com/actions/cache). It would look something like:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Clone project
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - name: Cache dependencies
        id: cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ./node_modules
          key: modules-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: npm ci
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
```

To verify it, you can run the build once, then run the same build again. The subsequent run should be faster. You can also verify in the output that the "Install dependencies" (or whatever name you give it) is skipped.

[image: cache hit and skipped install step]

Note: the display above will be what you see with explicitly defined steps like the config above. More complex setups might bundle all of this in an action, but you would still

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason I want a method to determine if modules got installed from cache or not is because I’ve spent a week trying to set up a cache like you describe and it simply does not appear to work. Install times remain constant. When I post on SO, people ask me, “how are you determining if modules got installed from cache?”. Do you know the answer to that question?

Comment: Also all docs I’ve read say to use path: ~/.npm, what’s your logic in using path: ./node_modules ? Note that lots of answers recommend to not do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67136614/cache-node-modules-in-github-actions

Comment: Sorry, I missed your reply here. Updated the answer.

Comment: As far as your second comment, ~/.npm would be where you store global installs, not project level installs. Honestly, I don't ever recommend global installs, even on your local machine. Put them in the project dependencies and `npx some-command` if you need a dependency with a cli. The suggestion not to use `node_modules` is because the person posting that question was using `yarn` as the package manager.

Comment: Npm cache is just for global dependencies?? That’s odd, in all the stuff I’ve read I don’t remember that being mentioned. Why would they bother differentiating?

Comment: I misspoke a bit there, `~/.npm` is where would cache the tarballs. Then `npm install` would install into `node_modules` by extracting all of those tarballs. You'd be "caching the cache". That 2 step process is generally pointless, though. The end result you want is a populated `node_modules` in the project, so just caching the end result leaves less work for it to do. I suppose there is a potential problem there if a) you ever change the OS used by the job, or b) you have things that manually mutate `node_modules`, such as `prisma`.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details, I’ll run some tests - What’s you view on using the setup-node cache feature?

Comment: No experience with it, sorry. The README isn't terribly clear about what it actually does, TBH. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I’ve tried your method. What I found was that the cache action never actually creates the initial cache, even after running it several times. It only ever reports “no cache found” then installs from network.

Comment: Not sure then. My screenshot above is from a build with that exact configuration. Only other thing I can think is that something else in your pipeline is changing the lock somehow. Is the hash that is says isn't found the same for each run? It will output the hash either way, e.g. `Cache not found for input keys: modules-39481100da339a315f686ad9211a1ad84f3cb128b6a43bc858f944f0da1db8d9`

Comment: I don’t think the lock file is being changed. It’s checked into the repo. I’ll check the hash is the same when I get a chance.