# Azure Web Apps: can't run any npm/yarn script that requires a dependency (commands are not found)

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I deployed a full-stack app to Azure Web Apps using Github Actions. The entire app is built by a GitHub Actions workflow and I set `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=false` (it should be the default anyway) in the Azure app settings to make sure the app is not rebuilt by Oryx.

Deploying my app, I discovered that any `package.json` script that calls a program installed as a project dependency fails because the program is not found. Let's just make a simple example (**this is just an illustrative example**):

```json
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node src/index.js"
```

would fail with error:

```
2021-10-29T15:45:34.947882335Z yarn run start
2021-10-29T15:45:36.587782173Z yarn run v1.17.3
2021-10-29T15:45:36.831333844Z $ cross-env NODE_ENV=production node src/index.js
2021-10-29T15:45:36.910516860Z /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/cross-env: 1: /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/cross-env: ../cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js: not found
2021-10-29T15:45:36.956014542Z error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

Now, don't focus on cross-env or the problem of starting the server. I've already solved that problem*. The point is: why does this happen?

Thank you.

(*) My latest "start" script was using pm2 to start the server. pm2 is installed in the container used by Azure so I could set the Azure App "start command" to call it rather than using yarn scripts.

Comment: Did you chained the yarn-commands with `&&` in `package.json`?

Answer (score 1):

In the situation of chaining yarn-commands with `&&` in package.json, it causes issues with creating `node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha.js` or other executable js files.

At that time, I got this type of error
`error Command failed with exit code 127` using yarn commands.

To get rid out of this error many times, tried the following steps:

1. Cleaned out node modules with this `rm -nf node_modules` from the root folder.
   Here you're using git, so you can add `/node_modules` to the `.gitignore` file, so you aren't saving libraries to your repo, and then later you can install dependencies by running `npm install`.
2. Using this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010294/how-to-cache-yarn-packages-in-github-actions), tried a few commands like:

- `yarn cache clean`
- `yarn install`
- `yarn start`
- `npm run build` or `yarn run build`

Comment: Yes, I have an `install:all` script in the project root that chains several yarn commands. Nonetheless, yesterday everything started working again for some mysterious unknown reason. Also, in all my tries, I also tested replacing that command with individual commands like `yarn install:server` (`cd server && yarn install`). I also tried to replace `yarn` with `npm`. I tried to build the shipped server package with Oryx (the client build is copied inside of it by GitHub Action). Nothing solved the problem. Yesterday some miracle happened \_("/)_/.

Comment: Nonetheless I'm caching packages in GitHub actions. But that doesn't mean that the `node_modules` folder is cached, right? If it means that, it could explain why some tries didn't work. But it doesn't explain why it works now that I'm using `install:all`.

Comment: Also, locally everything has always worked as expected.

Comment: Well @janluke, yarn documentation doesn't given any hints, When I observed this kind of issue, tried adding node_modules in git ignore file and your followed steps, resolved for that time being.