# Caching npm dependency with github action

Tags: github, npm, caching, yarnpkg, github-actions

I want to cache npm dependencies so that I does not do npm install every time I push and instead just load it from cache.

I think github action support this now?: [How do I cache steps in GitHub actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55110729/how-do-i-cache-steps-in-github-actions)

Here are few cases

- If `package.json` changes, which means `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` changed so do npm install and update cache
- Extending my above point, the contributor could be doing both `yarn install` and `npm install`

From the same above question, I changed my github action to something like this

```
name: Tsc compilation test
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Cache NPM dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache-
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Test tsc
        run: npm run ts-compile-check
```

This still does `npm install` and haven't reduced my computation time for installing dependencies (So I am not sure if this is working correctly or not)

Then I did `yarn install axios` hoping it would update my cache but in post-install I see this as logged

```
Post job cleanup.
Cache hit occurred on the primary key Linux-npm-cache-, not saving cache.
```

So here is my questions, Is it possible to achieve

- If `package.json` changes, which means `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` changed so do `npm install` and update cache
- Extending my above point, the contributor could be doing both `yarn install` and `npm install`

And can someone explain me this

```
    with:
      path: ~/.npm
      key: ${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache-
```

Comment: Would another action like https://github.com/actions/cache work better? Or would another example like  https://github.com/tinovyatkin/alphabank-pay-node/blob/a4ef58615423a4d6388a4702c3130603136a3ec7/.github/workflows/npmpublish.yml shows a difference which would make your case work better?

Comment: See also https://github.com/ktmud/cached-dependencies#cache-configs for details about keys.

Comment: Is your package-lock.json checked in in your repo? If not, the cache key will not be correctly computed because the lock file is generated only in the next step.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to have efficient caching with GitHub actions there needs to be a `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` present. This file is automatically generated when installing packages. If you want more information about package-lock.json, [check out the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json).

Now there's the subject of whether npm and yarn should be used in the same project. [More about that subject here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589493/is-there-any-harm-in-using-npm-and-yarn-in-the-same-project).

Based on the question, let's assume that both a package-lock.json and yarn.lock exists. If you're only using one of both, feel free to remove one from below. The config below is for yarn version 2 which uses `yarn config get cacheFolder` to get the cache folder. For another yarn version [see the docs](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#node---yarn).

```yaml
name: Tsc compilation test
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get yarn cache directory path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn config get cacheFolder)"

      - name: Cache yarn dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

      - name: Cache npm dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: '~/.npm'
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install # or yarn install

      - name: Test tsc
        run: npm run ts-compile-check
```

That's it! Well except for one more thing. Above we're using `~/.npm` for caching npm dependencies. Performance wise it would be quicker to cache `**/node_modules` however in some cases this would introduce conflicts. Feel free to experiment to see which one works for you. More about that [here](https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/67) and [here](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#node---npm).

---

From your question you also asked to explain the following code:

```yaml
    with:
      path: ~/.npm
      key: ${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache-
```

https://github.com/actions/cache#usage:

> **path** - A list of files, directories, and wildcard patterns to cache and restore. See @actions/glob for supported patterns.
> **key** - An explicit key for restoring and saving the cache
> **restore-keys** - An ordered list of keys to use for restoring the cache if no cache hit occurred for key

Therefore the code above:

- `path` is the folder that will be cached/restored (where the dependencies are installed)
- `key` is a unique identifier for the path that will be cached. In this case it hashes the contents of any `**/package-lock.json` file using `hashFiles`. Basically when the package-lock.json file changes, that means that the dependencies changed, and the cache shouldn't be used.
- `restore-keys` is basically a default key to use in case there's no match for the `key`

Comment: This action will cache the npm deps, but it will not skip the `npm install`. In order for that to happen you need to add an id to the cache step, in example `id: cache-npm-deps` and then add `if: steps.cache-npm-deps.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'` to your Install dependencies step.

Comment: "Caching doesn't mean that you never have to install your dependencies. Rather, it means that Node.js can skip the downloading and compiling step for dependencies that haven't changed since the last time you installed them. When you run npm install or npm ci, Node.js will check your node_modules folder and your package-lock.json file. If the installed version of a package matches the version specified in package-lock.json, Node.js can use the cached version instead of downloading and compiling it again."