# Github Actions restored cache is not being used

Tags: github, caching, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm having hard time figuring out how to make the pipeline use the restored cache of npm modules.

Here's the manifest file:

```
jobs:
  setup-build-push-deploy:
    name: Setup, Build, Push, and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      # Checkout the repo
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup NodeJS
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '12.14'

      # Cache the npm node modules
      - name: Cache node modules
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        id: cache-node-modules
        env:
          CACHE_NAME: cache-node-modules
        with:
          # npm cache files are stored in `~/.npm` on Linux/macOS
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ env.CACHE_NAME }}-${{ hashFiles('app/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ env.CACHE_NAME }}-

      # Install NPM dependencies
      - name: Install Dependencies
        if: steps.cache-node-modules.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: |
          cd app/
          npm install

      # Compile Typescript to Javascript
      - name: Compile Typescript
        run: |
          cd app/
          npm run make
```

The "cache" step does make a successful cache hit, and therefore the "install dependencies" step is skipped. But then the "compile" step fails, because it cannot find any installed npm modules.

[image]

The docs [here](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#node---npm) and [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#using-the-cache-action) and the SO question, eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64226272/caching-npm-dependency-with-github-action), do not specify any *certain* step or configuration that points towards *where to pick up the cached modules from*. Seems like they should be picked up automatically from `~/.npm`, but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by changing the path to `node_modules`:

Here's an example:

```yaml
jobs:
  prepare-npm-cache:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 12.22.0
      - name: Cache node modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: npm_cache_id
        with:
          path: node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-npm-cache-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-npm-cache-
            ${{ runner.os }}-

      - name: Install Dependencies
        if: steps.npm_cache_id.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: npm ci
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the exact same situation.
The `node_modules` seems to be cached but then the next job immediately fails due to missing dependencies.

I ended up using this [GitHub action](https://github.com/bahmutov/npm-install) by Gleb Bahmutov.

Specifically this part:

```
  - uses: bahmutov/npm-install@v1.4.5
  - run: npm install
  - run: npm run ***
```

Detailed description can be found in this article:
https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/do-not-let-npm-cache-snowball/