# caching sam setup in github workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, sam

I have this reusable workflow:
`

```
test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: '3.8'

      - uses: aws-actions/setup-sam@v2

      - name: build
        run: sam build --beta-features
```

`
I call this workflow with a matrix from outside. However the setup=-sam@v2 is taking a lot of time: around 26secs. Is it possible to cache this between matrix runs?
Thanks

Trying to fasten the setup of sam in github workflow

Answer (score 0):

Matrix strategy is used per job, so one possibility is to pull this

```
- name: build
  run: sam build --beta-features
```

into a separate job instance. Then you will use with matrix strategy only this part:

```
- name: build
  run: sam build --beta-features
```

If you want to use caching try sth like:

```
test:
  name: Test
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: '3.8'

    - name: Cache sam
        id: cache-sam
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: <specify the path>
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-sam

    - uses: aws-actions/setup-sam@v2
      if: steps.cache-sam.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'

    - name: build
      run: sam build --beta-features
```

However, we have to provide a path in the above code snipped. Maybe the installation path will be good.

Please check out the following links:

1. https://github.com/actions/cache
2. [How do I cache steps in GitHub actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55110729/how-do-i-cache-steps-in-github-actions)